# Both PHP statements are executing

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with the ACF plugin in WordPress.  For some reason the else statement is executing even when the first statement is true.  Why?

```
            <section id="ParksContainer" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <h1 id="AdventurePostTitle" class="">Parks</h1>

                <?php if( have_rows('adventure_location') ): 

                    while( have_rows('adventure_location') ): the_row(); ?>

                            <ul id="LocationUl">
                                <li><b>NATIONAL PARK:</b> &nbsp; 
                                        <?php if( the_sub_field('national_park') ):?> 

                                            <?php echo '<span class="LocationNameSpan">'; the_sub_field('national_park');  echo '</span>'; ?>

                                            <?php else: ?>

                                            <?php echo '<span class="LocationNameSpan">N/A</span>'; ?>                                          

                                         <?php endif; ?>
                                 </li>
                                <li>
                                    <b>STATE PARK:</b> &nbsp; 
                                                <?php if( the_sub_field('state_park') )  {

                                                echo '<span class="LocationNameSpan">'; the_sub_field('state_park');  echo '</span>';

                                            } else {

                                                echo '<span class="LocationNameSpan">N/A</span>';       
                                            }

                                         ?>
                                </li>                               
                            </ul>   

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </section><!--Parks Container-->
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: which if else your are referring to?

Comment: The national parks section and the state parks section are executing both statements.  However, if we look at the National Parks section both of these are executing                                                                                                <?php echo '<span class="LocationNameSpan">'; the_sub_field('national_park');  echo '</span>'; ?>

                                            <?php else: ?>

                                            <?php echo '<span class="LocationNameSpan">N/A</span>'; ?>

Comment: So I am getting the result Zion and N/A

Comment: not the answer but when you write if else follow same pattern `if(){}` of `if():`.personally i use first one

Comment: Yes.  I just tried both patterns to see if I could get it to work either way.  The code looks good to me so I'm stumped.

Comment: Well this is a classic case where you "think" it should be true and the code is telling you it "thinks" its false. So the code is doing what you are telling it. So you find out what is actually going on by var_dump() or print_r() the item in question and see what is going on. And work through it that way.

Comment: var_dump() of what?  What variable would i check?

Comment: if(get_sub_field()){}..

Comment: the_sub_field() is echoing and destroying your statements.